# How to handle errors in Azure DevOps pipelines in yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, event-handling, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, I have some pipelines in yaml files that execute tasks in Terraform and PowerShell to deploy infrastructures in Azure.

I would like to trigger a default action (like printing a default error message or delete somethings, etc.) if there is an error during the deployment, no matter if the error is from a Terraform script or PowerShell.

I think that the Yaml file can handle this action, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding a task at the end of your deployment job with a special condition to make sure it runs only if the pipeline has failed; [the docs explain the use of these kinds of condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> You can specify conditions under which a step, job, or stage will run.
>
> - Only when all previous dependencies with the same agent pool have succeeded. If you have different agent pools, those stages or jobs
>   will run concurrently. This is the default if there is not a condition
>   set in the YAML.
> - Even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled. Use `succeededOrFailed()` in the YAML for this condition.
> - Even if a previous dependency has failed, even if the run was canceled. Use `always()` in the YAML for this condition.
> - **Only when a previous dependency has failed. Use `failed()` in the YAML for this condition.**